# Origin of the friction equation

Tags: friction

$ F_M = \mu F_R $, where $ F_M $ is the maximum force due to friction, $ \mu $ is the coefficient of friction and $ F_R $ is the normal reaction force.

Where does the above come from? I understand that $ \mu $ is defined as such, but how can we show that the relationship is between $ F_M $ and $ F_R $, rather than $ F_M $ and some other variable? If we know for certain that only the normal reaction force is involved, how can we determine that $ F_M \propto F_R $ rather than, say, $ F_M \propto F_R^2 $, other than through observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We determine it empirically.  We did a bunch of tests, and that's the equation that fit.

By contrast, air friction is indeed proportional the the velocity squared.

In reality, $F_M=\mu F_R$ is actually just an empirical approximation.  The real systems can be much more complex.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction):

> While it is often stated that the COF is a "material property," it is better categorized as a "system property." Unlike true material properties (such as conductivity, dielectric constant, yield strength), the COF for any two materials depends on system variables like temperature, velocity, atmosphere and also what are now popularly described as aging and deaging times; as well as on geometric properties of the interface between the materials. For example, a copper pin sliding against a thick copper plate can have a COF that varies from 0.6 at low speeds (metal sliding against metal) to below 0.2 at high speeds when the copper surface begins to melt due to frictional heating. The latter speed, of course, does not determine the COF uniquely; if the pin diameter is increased so that the frictional heating is removed rapidly, the temperature drops, the pin remains solid and the COF rises to that of a 'low speed' test.